# How to find out the cause of Android logcat message "Skipped n frames. Too much work on main thread"

Tags: android, profiling, logcat

I am developing an android app with a lot of image processing and logcat frequently shows me `"Skipped n frames...."` messages.

The question is "How to **trace** the cause of those messages?". I do understand what it means (ie. creating AsyncTasks, etc), I just need to find out which part of my code that caused it.

Is there anyway to do this on Eclipse ADT? (perhaps something like database profiler found in some web frameworks)

Comment: u need to use AsyncTask

Comment: a simple suggestion would be is, to make sure any operations that doesn't have to rely on user interaction is being handled on background thread. For example, if you are scaling a bitmap, then do it in another thread and not in main UI thread.

Comment: He is asking how to trace to the part of code that cause this...

Comment: @MT8 I already know that. What I need to know is the causing part.

Comment: ohh, actually since u are working on image process as u mentioned in question, handling lot of Image makes ANR.. so there is possiblity of force close or u can make thumbimage of all the bitmaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use tracing tool from Android SDK: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll give it a try. Any specific clue on using android tracer to trace my problem (skipped frames)?

Comment: Just trace activity in main (UI) thread, you shouln't block main thread for more than approximately 16 ms, less is better.